# Looking for Django Social Network App Example

Tags: python, django

I have learned Django for a while, and now I am trying to find an example of social network app in Django, with basic functionality such as Follow, Vote, User Profile, Activity Feed, etc.

Pinax framework (based on Django) does not update its pinax-project-social anymore, as it is still 2 years ago in Django==1.6.5.

Other Django packages I found are specifically for user management or other aspects.

Could anyone provide some information on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, this can help you.

> Bootcamp is an open source enterprise social network built with Python
>   using the Django Web Framework.

[BootCamp](https://github.com/vitorfs/bootcamp)

The project has **three basic apps**:

> Feed (A Twitter-like microblog)
>   Articles (A collaborative blog)
>   Question & Answers (A Stack Overflow-like platform)

Comment: Yea, I came across with that before. Seems it lack the voting/following capability.

Comment: They have, in the Question & Answer session, a upvote, downvote and favorite.